# Why SVNVersion.exe is returning Unversioned Directory

Tags: svn, c#-4.0, tortoisesvn, msbuild-task

I am trying to mark my make project build with SVN revision number.

I am using MsBuildTask for updating the AssemblyVersionFile details.

I am using the following BuildScript to get the info , but this is returning -1 as SVNVersion.exe is returning Unversioned Directory, How do I update SVNVersion.exe

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <SvnVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" ToolPath="$(ProgramFiles)\TortoiseSVN\bin">

   <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />

    </SvnVersion>


    <FileUpdate Files="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
     Regex="(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"
  ReplacementText="$1.$2.$3.$(Revision)" />

</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must **not update** svnversion (for which reasons you think update is solution), but get correct, working string** for running svnversion, in order to get result.

Read `svnversion --help`, note format of command line

`svnversion [OPTIONS] [WC_PATH [TRAIL_URL]]`

and remark

> If WC_PATH is an unversioned path, the program will output
>     'Unversioned directory' or 'Unversioned file'.

I.e - build command-line for task, which **check needed you versioned directory**, not some strange non-WC location

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a old version of svnversion.

Try to open the Command Line Prompt, navigate to the svnversion directory and do the same job as the MSBuild.

CMD:

```
cd C:\ProgramFiles\TortoiseSVN\bin
[ENTER]
svnversion C:\VisualStudio\Projects\YourDirectory
[ENTER]

SVNVERSION should answer why its not working, in my case was by E155021: This client is too old to work with thew working copy at...
```

Comment: Is `svnversion` a part of the TortioseSVN distribution? I can't find it in my `/bin` folder.

Comment: Yes, it is was a part of the command line tools package, which I did not install initially. Just had to re-run the installer and update the installation.